# Mimic the behavior of a <select>, <option> with a <ul>, <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

Actually i'm stuck on my dropdown menu. I want to imitate the behavior of a **select**, **option** with a **ul**, **li**.

If I click on the second **li** I want it to take the place of the first **li** without deleting the latter.

**Like** the behavior of the method **appendChild**() but **without removing** the old element.

```js
const listMenu = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'))
const menu = document.querySelector('ul')

const arrow = document.querySelector('ul')

let isDisplay = true

function openMenu() {
    listMenu.slice(1).forEach(list => {
        list.style.display = 'block'
        arrow.classList.add('arrow-up')
        isDisplay = false
    })
}

function closeMenu() {
    listMenu.slice(1).forEach(list => {
        list.style.display = 'none'
        arrow.classList.remove('arrow-up')
        isDisplay = true
    })
}

function displayMenu() {
    if (isDisplay) {
        openMenu()
    } else {
        closeMenu()
    }
}

closeMenu()

menu.addEventListener('click', displayMenu)
```

```css
ul {
    width: 170px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #901c1c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    background-color: #901c1c;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
    position: relative;
}

li:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 22px;
    width: 0.6em;
    height: 0.6em;
    border-left: 0.2rem solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom: 0.2rem solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.arrow-up::after {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    top: 28px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="popularity">Popularité</li>
    <li id="date">Date</li>
    <li id="title">Titre</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you want to imitate the select behaviour?

Comment: Because i can't have this design on select menu :/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

That's why i use UL and LI

Comment: The question related yo your comment seems can help you....

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery you can do something like this,
where you toggle a class `.open` and show specify it in `css`.

Whenever one clicks on a list item, this item will be prepended to the list and the class `.open` will be removed from the parent and css specifies to only show the first item of the list:

```
ul:not(.open) li:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

menu.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{

  let listItem = e.target;
  
  if(menu.classList.contains('open'))
    menu.prepend(listItem);
  
  listItem.closest('ul').classList.toggle('open');
  
})
```

```css
ul {
    width: 170px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #901c1c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    background-color: #901c1c;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
    position: relative;
}

li:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 22px;
    width: 0.6em;
    height: 0.6em;
    border-left: 0.2rem solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom: 0.2rem solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    transition: transform .3s;
}

ul.open::after {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.arrow-up::after {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    top: 28px;
}

ul:not(.open) li:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="popularity">Popularité</li>
    <li id="date">Date</li>
    <li id="title">Titre</li>
</ul>
```

With multiple menus as requested:

```js
const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');

menus.forEach(menu =>{
  
  menu.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{

    let listItem = e.target;

    if(menu.classList.contains('open'))
      menu.prepend(listItem);

    listItem.closest('ul').classList.toggle('open');

  });
  
});
```

```css
ul {
    width: 170px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #901c1c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li {
    background-color: #901c1c;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
    position: relative;
}

li:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 22px;
    width: 0.6em;
    height: 0.6em;
    border-left: 0.2rem solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom: 0.2rem solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    transition: transform .3s;
}

ul.open::after {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.arrow-up::after {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    top: 28px;
}

ul:not(.open) li:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="popularity">Popularité</li>
    <li id="date">Date</li>
    <li id="title">Titre</li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu">
    <li id="popularity2">Popularité</li>
    <li id="date2">Date</li>
    <li id="title2">Titre</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I successfully implemented this for one drop-down menu on a page, but when creating a second drop-down menu on the same page, the second menu doesn't drop-down. Is there some subtlety in the CSS that prevents one from using this CSS for two different drop-down menus on the same page?

Comment: @JamesNorris, I included an example with an additional menu, you can add as many as needed.

Comment: @prettyInPink--Thanks! But I've spent the last couple of days working my way to a solution based on your answer and just posted it as an answer here. Let me know what you think of my solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Working from @prettyInPink's suggested solution, this is the non-jQuery solution I came up with.

This javascript can go anywhere in the file (I think)--I have it in the header.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    
        function ChangeDropdowns(select_xx)
        {
            bool_debug = false;
            
            arr_menu = document.getElementsByClassName("state");
            
            if (bool_debug) { str_menu = "<?php echo  'header-games.php:ChangeDropdowns - '.__LINE__; ?>" + ":\n\n" + "select_xx = " + select_xx + "\n" + "arr_menu.length = " + arr_menu.length + "\n"; }
            
                if (select_xx.slice(0, 6) == "select") { str_country = select_xx.slice(-2); }
                else { str_country = select_xx.slice(0, 2); }

                for (count=0; count<arr_menu.length; count++)
                {
                    if (bool_debug) 
                    { 
                        str_menu += "str_country = " + str_country + " - ";
                        str_menu += "arr_menu["+ count + "].id.slice(-2) = " + arr_menu[count].id.slice(-2) + "\n";
                        str_menu += "arr_menu[" + count + "] = " + arr_menu[count].id;
                    } // if (bool_debug)
    
                    if (str_country == arr_menu[count].id.slice(-2)) 
                    { 
                        document.getElementById(arr_menu[count].id).style.display="flex"; 
                        if (bool_debug) { str_menu += " - displaying" + "\n"; } 
                    } // if (("states_" + select_xx) == arr_menu[count].id)
                    else
                    { 
                        document.getElementById(arr_menu[count].id).style.display="none"; 
                        if (bool_debug) { str_menu += " - hiding" + "\n"; } 
                    } // if (("states_" + select_xx) == arr_menu[count].id) else
                } // for (count=0; count<arr_menu.length; count++)
            
            if (bool_debug) { alert(str_menu); }
                                
        } // function ChangeDropdowns(select_xx)

    </script>
```

This is the first drop-down menu:

```
<ul id="ul_XX" class="menu country">
    <li id="select_XX" onclick="test(this.id);">Please Choose Nation of Residence</li>
    <li id="us">United States</li>
    <li id="gu">Guam</li>
    <li id="pr">Puerto Rico</li>
    <li id="um">United States Minor Outlying Islands</li>
    <li id="vi">Virgin Islands, U.S.</li>
    <li id="au">Australia</li>
    <li id="ca">Canada</li>
    <li id="va">Holy See (Vatican City State)</li>
    <li id="ie">Ireland</li>
    <li id="im">Isle of Man</li>
    <li id="gb">United Kingdom</li>
    <li id="vg">Virgin Islands, British</li>
</ul>
```

The `<ul>` for the states for the "United States" is awfully long, so I'll just give you the `<ul>`'s for the "United States Minor Outlying Islands" and "Virgin Islands, U.S.":

```
<ul id="ul_vg" class="menu state twoup">
    <li id="select_vg" onclick="test(this.id)">Please Choose Island of Residence</li>
    <li id="vg_AN">Anegada</li>
    <li id="vg_VD">Jost Van Dyke</li>
    <li id="vg_TO">Totola</li>
    <li id="vg_VG">Virgin Gorda</li>
</ul>

<ul id="ul_vi" class="menu state twoup">
    <li id="select_vi" onclick="test(this.id)">Please Choose Island of Residence</li>
    <li id="vi_SC">Saint Croix</li>
    <li id="vi_SJ">Saint John</li>
    <li id="vi_ST">Saint Thomas</li>
</ul>
```

This javascript has to go after your last second-level menu--I'm not sure why. :-(

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    function test(select_xx)
    {   
        bool_debug = false;
    
        const menu = document.getElementById("ul_" + select_xx.slice(-2));

        if (bool_debug)
        {
            str_nodes = "<?php echo  'function index.php:test(select_xx) - '.__LINE__; ?>" + ":\n\n" ;
            str_nodes += "select_xx = " + select_xx + "\n";
            for (let count = 0; count < menu.length; count++) 
            {
                str_nodes += "node[" + count + "] = " + menu[count].id + "\n";
            } // for (let count = 0; count < nodeList.length; count++)
            str_nodes += "\n" + "ul_" + select_xx.substr(-2);
            alert(str_nodes);
        } // if (bool_debug)

        menu.addEventListener("click", (e)=>
            {
                bool_debug = false;
                
                let listItem = e.target;
    
                if (bool_debug) { alert("<?php echo  'function index.php:test(select_xx) - '.__LINE__; ?>:\n\n" + "listItem.id = " + listItem.id); }
          
                if(menu.classList.contains("open")) { menu.prepend(listItem) };
          
                listItem.closest("ul").classList.toggle("open");
                
                ChangeDropdowns(listItem.id);
            } // "click", (e)=>
        ) // ul_select_xx.addEventListener("click", (e)=>
        
    } // function test()

</script>
```

I had to do a lot of debugging to get this to work, and I'm leaving what debugging code I needed in case you need it--obviously you can delete this from your code when/if it works for you.

You can see this code working in its full glory at https://www.ocetacea.net/Games/indextest.php

I hope this helps.